# CAST nvarchar to int when ISNUMERIC equal 1

Tags: sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I have table with `varchar` column.
What I need to do is select all rows which have numeric value in this column but value between 100 and 150
Below sample code with some data:

```
create table test (number nvarchar(10))

insert into test (number) values ('100'), ('140'), ('222ass'), ('2'), ('some text')
```

The first thought that comes to mind:

```
select * from test where isnumeric(number) = 1 and cast(number as int) between 100 and 150
```

But ERROR:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'some text' to data type int.
```

NOTE: When field is `varchar` - this code works fine.

Next try. I use subquery. Why? I thought that in subquery I will have right value (condition `ISNUMERIC` in subquery) and than I can with no problem make cast:

```
select 
  number
from (
  SELECT 
    number
  FROM test 
  where isnumeric(number) = 1) ds 
where number between 100 and 150
```

But ERROR too (the same as above)

After this error I grabbed a last hope (the current way of thinking). I added a third subquery :)

```
select * 
from (
  select 
    cast(number as int) n 
  from (
    SELECT 
      number
    FROM test 
    where isnumeric(number) = 1) ds 
) ds2
where n between 100 and 150
```

But ERROR again :(

Any idea how to resolve my problem?
I also be glad to find out why I get this errors. Why MSSQL don't want to cast my data?

Thanks for help!

PS. MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: You have no control over the processing order of predicates in your where clause. To short circuit that you would have to use a query/cte to first isolate the rows where isnumeric = 1. Then you could do a second query to check the range. Be careful here...isnumeric does NOT mean the value can be cast as an int. That function allows a lot of stuff through.

Comment: I did it. In second and third example. First I isolate rows where ISNUMERIC = 1 (this is new dataset) Next I select from it. But still error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` like this:

```
SELECT number
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN isnumeric(number) = 1 THEN number
              ELSE CAST (NULL AS int)
         END AS number         
  FROM test) t
WHERE number BETWEEN 100 and 150
```

Comment: Nice! Can you explain me why I need to use case? In my example my subquery is "filtered" and have only right values. But MSSQL says thay I have there not numeric values. Which is not true

Comment: SQL Server does not evaluate WHERE clauses left to right as a programming language would. It runs it through an optimizer and re-evaluates the statement to be most optimal for the query plan. CASE statements, however, are not optimized in such a way, and are processed left to right.

Comment: Thanks for help and @Brandon thanks for explanaition!

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL Server 2012 or higher, [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) will solve your problem:

```
TRY_CONVERT(int, number)
```

returns `number` converted to an `int`, if such a conversion is possible, or `NULL` otherwise.